# What is wrong with this trigger syntax?

Tags: mysql

Look at this code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_product_insert` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_product_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `products`
    FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE `categories` SET product_count=product_count+1 where id = NEW.category_id;
END$$
```

This runs ok but shows some error. Here is the output:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
```

So, even though the trigger is created - the script (containing this triggers) dies because of error. This might be really simple but somehow I am missing the point. Help anyone?

Comment: Can you try to change: `where id=` into `where categories.id=` ? I guess that an `id` field exists in both tables.

Comment: You also have an `END` without a `BEGIN`. You either remove the `END` or add a `BEGIN`.

Comment: 'id' wont create problems as the id is used in context of 'update categories' statement. Thanks for the END-BEGIN though. Was a terrible mistake by me. Wasted hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>It is a two table trigger, so `id` is probably ambiguous.  Add the table name to it.  It wouldn't hurt to add the table name to every field reference to be crystal clear.</s>

Never mind that.  There is no `BEGIN` before the `UPDATE`.  The `FOR` statement seems to expect `BEGIN` and `END` around the statements to execute.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_product_insert` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_product_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `products`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE `categories`
      SET product_count=product_count+1
      WHERE id = NEW.category_id;
  END$$
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed it. I wonder why mysql workbench generated the statements without 'begin'.

Comment: @Vikash: You don't need the BEGIN-END if it's only one statement.